# Templated read (like scanf)

Tags: bash, perl

I've got a shell script variable, which currently is defined like this:

```
tsource=/backup/%HOST%/%SHARE%/%PERIOD%
```

I want to match this template to another variable, which might have a value like this:

```
psource=/backup/somehost/someshare/monthly.1
```

My aim is to generate the following assignments so that I can use them for a substitution later in the script:

```
vars[HOST]=somehost
vars[SHARE]=someshare
vars[PERIOD]=monthly.1
```

I should point out that the user can override both these values and we might end up with different (but still matching) shapes, which means that a simple "split at `/`" (or even "split at punctuation") is insufficient:

```
tsource=/backup/%PERIOD/where/%HOST%-%SHARE%
psource=/backup/monthly.1/where/somehost-someshare
```

The intention is to be able to parse `$psource` based on the template provided by `$tsource`. As it's utility software I don't really care if the user tries to break it - it'll bail at a later point if insufficient or invalid parameters have been provided.

Looking at possible solutions I think something like `sscanf` could be useful here, which is a tool that's indirectly available to me. I can easily enough manipulate `$tsource` to extract `HOST`, `SHARE`, and `PERIOD`, and derive a `sscanf` template:

```
grep -Po "(?<=%)[[:upper:]]+(?=%)" <<<"$tsource"           # "HOST" "SHARE" "PERIOD"
tscanf=$(sed -re 's/%[[:upper:]]+%/%s/g' <<<"$tsource")    # "/backup/%s/%s/%s"
```

This would allow me to apply the template in Perl, like this example:

```
perl -MString::Scanf -e '
    $psource = "/backup/somehost/someshare/monthly.1";
    $tscanf = "/backup/%s/%s/%s";
    ($host, $source, $period) = sscanf($tscanf, $psource);
    print "host=$host, share=$share, period=$period\n"
'
# "host=somehost, share=someshare, period=monthly.1"
```

(If I was going to dive into Perl I'd probably do the template rewriting and `sscanf` generation in the Perl part too, but let's park that for now.)

However, it grates somewhat writing a shell script that needs `perl`.

Is there an alternative (better) solution that allows me to map values from a string for fairly arbitrary labels in a template, that doesn't involve a quick dive into Perl?

Comment: Why not simply use something like `IFS='/' read -ra vars <<< $(echo ${psource#/*/})`?; this'll give you your values in the array `vars`: `vars[0]` would be: `somehost`, and so on

Comment: @matsib.dev thanks. I've updated my question with a second example to show why that won't work. I've also commented under your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is using regular expressions an option? I still had to shell out to `sed` to cleanly replace `%...%` with `(.*)`, though:

```
$ psource=/backup/monthly.1/where/somehost-someshare
$ tsource=/backup/%PERIOD%/where/%HOST%-%SHARE%
$ # replace labels with '(.*)', need sed to avoid greediness of * in ${../../..}
$ tsource_re=$(sed 's/%[^%]*%/(.*)/g' <<<"${tsource}")
$ # match against tsource to get template names
$ [[ $tsource =~ $tsource_re ]]; tmatch=(${BASH_REMATCH[@]:1})
$ # match against psource to get template values
$ [[ $psource =~ $tsource_re ]]; pmatch=(${BASH_REMATCH[@]:1})
$ for i in ${!tmatch[@]}; do printf "%s:\t%s\n" "${tmatch[$i]}" "${pmatch[$i]}"; done
%PERIOD%:   monthly.1
%HOST%: somehost
%SHARE%:    someshare
```

Comment: That looks like it does the job, thank you very much. The only significant change is that I've created a `psource_re=$(sed 's/%[^%]*%/(.*)/g' <<<"${tsource}")` for matching against the `$psource` value so that the percent symbols can be discarded.

Answer (score 1):

this should do the trick:

```bsh
tsource='/backup/%HOST%/%SHARE%/%PERIOD%'
psource='/backup/somehost/someshare/monthly.1'
IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -ra var_names <<< $(grep -Po "(?<=%)[[:upper:]]+(?=%)" <<< "$tsource")
IFS='/' read -ra var_values <<< $(echo ${psource#/*/})
declare -A vars=( ["${var_names[0]}"]="${var_values[0]}" ["${var_names[1]}"]="${var_values[1]}" ["${var_names[2]}"]="${var_values[2]}" )
```

---

`echo ${vars[HOST]} ${vars[SHARE]} ${vars[PERIOD]}`

> `somehost someshare monthly.1`

Comment: Thank you matsib.dev. I'm going to +1 this because it does address the specific example I quoted. Unfortunately it doesn't handle my general case (which is why I described the scheme as _templating_) so I can't accept it as an answer. I've updated my question to include a second example.